# Make field required only in specific areas?

Tags: tfs, customization

Is it possible to modify a TFS 2010 Process Template such that a field is required only for specific areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using WHEN Condition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194966.aspx